# How to count total views of all YouTube live streams in search results using xpath in DevTools console?

Tags: xpath, youtube, console, devtools

I'm trying to count the total amount of viewers watching multiple YouTube live streams of a single event (Michael Cohen Congressional Hearing) that's being live streamed by dozens of accounts (with hundreds of thousands people watching) simultaneously. How can I count the total viewers of all the streams for the event in the Chrome DevTools Console using xpath `//*[@id="metadata-line"]/span` to the view count elements of each video on the [search results page](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=michael%20cohen&sp=CAMSAkAB). (I searched "Michael Cohen" filtered by live, sorted by view count)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use JS path instead:

```
// Get the total of "li" elements in the current page:
var qtyResultsPerPage = document.querySelectorAll('#item-section-185938 > li').length;

// Variable which will get the sum of all visualizations.
var totalViewsPerPage = 0;

// Loop the "li" elements:
for (var incr = 1; incr < qtyResultsPerPage; incr++) {

  // Sum in the "totalViewsPerPage" variable the retrieved value in the iteration.
  // NOTE: The "dot" is removed (excluding also the words).
  totalViewsPerPage += parseFloat(document.querySelector('#item-section-185938 > li:nth-child(' + incr + ') > div > div > div.yt-lockup-content > div.yt-lockup-meta > ul > li').innerText.split(" ")[0].replace(".", ""));
}

// Show the total:
console.log("Total views: " + totalViewsPerPage);
```

> N.B the value of `item-section-` vary when the page is reloaded. Also,
>   this sample retrieves only the visualizations available in the current
>   page.

You can also use the YouTube Data API for get these results. This is a [demo](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.videos.list?part=statistics&id=xF0TO0yU834&fields=items%252Fstatistics&_h=6&) you can use.

Comment: I'm not sure you understood me. I'm not trying to get the value from a video's page, but to get the 'watching' from all the the results on the [search results page](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=michael%20cohen&sp=CAMSAkAB) since there's dozens of the same live stream

Comment: So I'm going a little nuts here. I don't think were dealing with the same elements names/structure.  My page looks like this: `document.querySelector('#items > ytd-video-renderer:nth-child(1)')` where 1 iterates for each result

Comment: @xion, sorry, but, what do yo mean *(My page looks like this)*? - are you looking in the YouTube search results *(as you did [linked(https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=michael%20cohen&sp=CAMSAkAB) in your question])*. Check yourself in my answer that I verify first how many li elements are, later I made a for loop for iterate each li element.